# Bounded Surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with infinite surface area

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Does there exist a bounded surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with infinite surface area? Would prefer something without boundary and compact, but any example works. The one dimensional analogue to this would be a space filling curve, though this is only an immersion

Edit: ideally without boundary, compact, and $C^1$

Edit: If it's C^1 and compact then it will have finite area necessarily

Comment: Do you mean smething like Koch Curve but in $\Bbb R^3$? Probably you can do something similar starting with a regular Tetrahedron.

Comment: @TitoEliatron right something like this - I guess taking the direct product of the Koch curve with the unit interval handles case where boundary is allowed. Do you think something similar could work to produce a surface where there is no boundary?

Comment: See [The Koch Curve in Tree dimension](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262600735_The_Koch_curve_in_three_dimensions).

Comment: If it is compact and $C^1$ then the area will be always finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example, start with a Koch curve in the right half plane $\{(x,y,z) \mid x > 0, y=0\} \subset \mathbb R^3$, and then revolve it around the $z$ axis to get a surface of revolution. You'll get a surface that is homeomorphic to a torus, i.e. the surface of revolution of an ordinary round torus. But, it will have infinite area.